# Eclipse and LibGDX: Problems with playing music on exported jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libgdx, audio

I have a program that works fine in Eclipse; The music works fine. However, when I export it into a runnable jar with libraries packaged into the jar, the music doesn't play. The music file is in the right directory, I extracted the jar and checked. The sound effects also work fine. It's just the music that doesn't work.

I don't think it's a problem with the file, because I exported the jar, extracted the jar, opened the folder with the extracted files, and clicked on the music file to play it, and it worked fine....Any help?

Here is the code:

```
package com.me.mygame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;

public class MyGame extends Game {
    Game game;
    Music music;

    @Override
    public void create() {  
        music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("Music.wav"));
        music.setLooping(true);
        music.play();

        game = this;
        setScreen(new Splash(game));
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        music.dispose();
    }
}
```

The Music.wav file is in the android project's assets folder, which is how you're conventionally supposed to store resources with LibGdx. What confuses me is that the SFX work, but it's just the music that doesn't work, and they're in the same directory. As I said, the music file gets put into the jar file, because I'm able to extract it, find it, and play it from the extracted folder.

Comment: loading and playing code?

Comment: How are you accessing the music? For example you can't use `File` when everything is in a jar.

Comment: Do start the program from command line with `java -jar game.jar` and check if any errors occure. Also add a logger where you start playing and check if it get played. Else you need to provide the code where you start playing the music

Comment: use Gdx.files.classpath(java.lang.String path) to reference your music file.

Comment: I updated my question with the code posted.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, everybody. I solved it; I converted my file from a WAV to an MP3. I guess Eclipse has problems with WAV files, if they're too big, because my Music.wav which was around 7mb wouldn't work, but my Soundeffect.wav which was less than 1mb worked fine. Thanks for all the answers anyways.

Comment: This is correct, though it's not a perfect solution since looping mp3's can cause a stutter where libgdx seems to loop wavs much more cleanly.

Comment: After working through this more, using .ogg files will also allow the runnable jar to stream the files, and do not cause a stutter when looping.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you need to know:

When you run from eclipse, you're simply dealing with files and you can deal with them simply.

when you've compiled your jar, things become slightly more complicated. For example, you need to access them in a different way, I'm not sure how LibGDX works but I hope these examples can help:

Create a folder in your `src` directory, I usually call it `res`, place your sound files in `/src/res/...`

Now when you want to access them you do

`getClass().getResource(String location);`

So you can do

`getClass().getResource("/res/soundfile.wav");` and this will return a URL to the given file which can be used.

If you need a stream you can do

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/soundfile.wav");` Which will give you the file in your compiled jar as an InputStream! This method will work on both the compiled and the eclipse version.

Comment: we are talking about libgdx here. There are already handler for that and they are working with internal and external files no need to write your own handler